# Java drawImage confusion

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

In my program I am drawing an image with

```
g.drawImage(image, 32, 32,  96  , 96, 11, 0, 13, 2, null);
```

I would expect this to start drawing the part of the image specified at {11,0}, {13,2} in the location in my program at {32,32} and finish at {96,96} however it does not! the `srcx` and `srcy` results act normally and they do grab the image that they need to. However something is going wrong with the `dcx` and the `dcy` parameters.

[image]

As we can clearly see for a start the image is 32 by 32 (I would expect a 64 by 64 square) and it is definitely not  being drawn from {32,32}  {96,96} can someone shed some light on whats going wrong? (only look at the square ignore the other 2 images they are being drawn elsewhere).

Comment: g.drawImage(image, 32, 32,  96  , 96, 11, 0, 13, 2, null); == read Oracle tutorial about 2D Graphics - Working with Images before posting an question about here

Comment: but I have read that which is why I am confused.he width and height dimensions on the destination area are calculated by the following expressions: (dstx2-dstx1), (dsty2-dsty1). My box should be 64 by 64 instead its 32 by 32. Something is clearly wrong here. Furthermore its not even being drawn from {32,32} which is where dstx and dty start from

Comment: override getPreferredSize or post an SSCCE

Comment: `g.drawImage(image, 32, 32,  96  , 96, 11, 0, 13, 2, null);` should best be `g.drawImage(image, 32, 32,  96  , 96, 11, 0, 13, 2, this);`

Comment: should it be this? the last argument is asking for an observer if I don't want the image to be observed surley it should be null